# Why is the color of the bars not filling and staying white? d3js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

The bars are showing the numbers and height correctly but  i can not change the color of the bar with anything it stays white for some reason while i have .bar in style tag that says its red and in the code a fill that says it red i dont understand why its white and not turning red?

```js
 var dataset = [80, 100, 56, 120, 180, 30, 40, 120, 160];

 var svgWidth = 500, svgHeight = 300, barPadding = 5;
 var barWidth = svgWidth / dataset.length;
 var svg = d3.select('svg')
.attr("width", svgWidth)
.attr("height", svgHeight);

 var barChart = svg.selectAll("rect")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("y", function (d) {
    return svgHeight -d;
})
.attr("height", function (d) {
    return d;
})
.attr("wdith", barWidth - barPadding)
.attr("class", "bar")
.attr("fill", "red")
.attr("transform", function (d, i) {
    var translate = [barWidth * i, 0];
    return "translate("+ translate +")";
});

 var text = svg.selectAll("text")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("text")
.text(function (d) {
    return d;
})
.attr("y", function (d, i) {
    return svgHeight - d - 2;
})
.attr("x", function(d, i){
    return barWidth * i;
})
.attr("fill","#A64C38");
```

```css
.bar {
color: red;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>

<svg class="bar-chart"></svg>
```

Comment: You have misspelled width attribute `.attr("wdith", barWidth - barPadding)` should be `.attr("width", barWidth - barPadding)` if you fix that it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

give the `rect` a `width`, and maybe an `x` not `transform`

Answer (score 0):

The only issue is the misspelled "width" attribute. As mentioned in the comment above. Here is the complete fixed code. You do not even need to specify class and css. The svg rect fill attribute should be able to give the color you want.

```js
 var dataset = [80, 100, 56, 120, 180, 30, 40, 120, 160];

 var svgWidth = 500, svgHeight = 300, barPadding = 5;
 var barWidth = svgWidth / dataset.length;
 var svg = d3.select('svg')
.attr("width", svgWidth)
.attr("height", svgHeight);

 var barChart = svg.selectAll("rect")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("y", function (d) {
    return svgHeight -d;
})
.attr("height", function (d) {
    return d;
})
.attr("width", barWidth - barPadding)
.attr("class", "bar")
.attr("fill", "red")
.attr("transform", function (d, i) {
    var translate = [barWidth * i, 0];
    return "translate("+ translate +")";
});

 var text = svg.selectAll("text")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("text")
.text(function (d) {
    return d;
})
.attr("y", function (d, i) {
    return svgHeight - d - 2;
})
.attr("x", function(d, i){
    return barWidth * i;
})
.attr("fill","#A64C38");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>

<svg class="bar-chart"></svg>
```